# What configuration parameter can cause physical damage to the screen?

Tags: display

During an interview, I was asked that whether a buggy or faulty display software driver can cause physical screen damage.

During discussion of that question, the interviewer mentioned that misconfiguration of an important screen parameter can cause that damage too. He stated that it is not the screen resolution. What would that parameter be?

I did ask him that question, but he wouldn't answer!

Comment: And that downvote because .... ??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On older CRTs, setting a too high frequency ([vertical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate) or [horizontal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_scan_rate) scan rate) can damage the electronics. (Newer CRTs just display an "Unsupported frequency" message.)

*(I accidentally destroyed one CRT this way by just booting a Linux Live CD, which picked 1600x1200 as default... it worked for a few minutes, then went blank permanently.)*

Comment: grawity: Is refresh rate the same as frequency?